# solution for html "intellisense" style completion for emacs like Atom or Brackets have

Tags: completion, auto-complete-mode, html

I've started taking an html course and I'm trying to figure out how to add functionality to emacs that exists in programs like atom or brackets. I've seen a few modes web-mode.el and nxhtml mentioned but they don't seem to have the same degree of completion.

Specifically for instance in either atom or brackets you can type for example `<img` and a context-popup will give you options for it such as "src= " "alt= " and the complete list of attributes etc. Is there similar autocomplete functionality somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

In stock Emacs, you can perform completion with `M-TAB`.  If you want a popup to appear magically, then you probably want to install and enable the `company` package, available from GNU ELPA.

The quality/quantity of the completion candidates depends on the major mode you use.  I personally use `nxml-mode` when I edit HTML files (which requires that I properly close my tags, but I find it a good idea anyway) which uses the XML schema to know the completions, so it's pretty good in my experience (but do install the `html5-schema` package from GNU ELPA, so you get an up-to-date schema, since the schema that comes with Emacs is for HTML4).

Comment: We don't have any "smart" completion for html-mode in stock Emacs though, do we?

Comment: If you use `nxml-mode` there is.

Comment: Even then, it seems to offer no completions in "normal" HTML files. Probably different for XHTML files, but there are not many of those left these days.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I always edit my HTML files with `nxml-mode` (using the `html5-schema` GNU ELPA package).

Comment: That's great (and should probably be mentioned in the answer). Too bad this doesn't help the cases where we have to use `html-mode` anyway (`mhtml-mode`, templating fragments, and so on).